# Как добавить в Excel-файл строку

Tags: delphi, excel

Работаю с excel через библиотеку `TXLSFile`. Как можно после (или перед) определенной строки вставить пустую строку?

Comment: написать алгоритм смещения строк пробовали?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, сам порылся в исходниках попробовал всё возможное. Оказывается, до ужаса просто -

```
xf.Workbook.Sheets[0].Rows.InsertRows(0,10);
```

Это, к примеру, вставит после 1 строки 10 строк.